# Updating data from Vuex get a infinite loop in watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a "dumb" component that just get props from a parent. The user can change a selector which fires an action (using Vuex) to get new data. When this new data has been received I want to pass it to the child and re-render that component with the new data. Unfortutalely I keep getting this warning in my watcher. Please help :slight_smile:

```
export default {
  name: 'bubbles',
  props: {
    awesomeData: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Best component ever'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    awesomeData (newData) {
      console.log('hello world')
      this.refreshSomethingAwesome(newData)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    refreshSomethingAwesome (newData) {}
  }
}
```

s

```
101 hello world
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "awesomeData"
```

I'm trying a solution pretty much exactly the same as this: [Vuex Examples](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/chat/components/MessageSection.vue)
But can't seem to get it working... hmmm

Comment: It's likely something you're doing in `refreshSomethingAwesome` but it's hard to tell. What you're doing just here wouldn't cause that.

Comment: Though, guessing by looking at this code, you can likely make this into a simple computed property. I'm willing to bet the infinite loop is due to you doing something like `this.awesomeData.sort/foo/somethingDestrutive()` instead of working off of a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the reason I was getting the loop was because I was actually trying to sort mutable data from the property (thought it was immutable)

```
let options = {
 children: newData.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
}
```

I changed it to something like:

```
const sortedNewData = [...newData].sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)

let options = {
 children: sortedNewData
}
```

**Note:** To prevent this across my app, I might wrap my initial state in a Map from `immutable.js`

```
import { Map, fromJS } from 'immutable'

const initialState = Map({
 awesomeData: fromJS([])
})
```

Helpful article: [alligator.io](https://alligator.io/vuejs/roundup-state-management-libraries/)